# how to setup browsing via OpenVPN?

Tags: windows, openvpn

I've setup OpenVPN and connected to the server; the tray icon shows everything is fine. However, my browser still doesn't use VPN. It shows my real IP, when I check it via a website. How can I make my browser send traffic through VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using the OpenVPN Access Server. It makes things much easier. Then, just login to the AS as the admin user (usually 'openvpn') and go to the "VPN Settings" page. There you will see the "Should client Internet traffic be routed through the VPN?" option. Just choose "yes" and save the settings. Then push the new settings to the AS.